# connect nokia BH 505 with windows 7

Tags: bluetooth, headset

I have tried on internet even blusolei as well but I am not able to connect my nokia bluetooth audio to windows 7 on my lenevo laptop G570.I have broadcom bluetooth drivers on my lenevo.

can anyone let me know incase anyone knows about it?